# SSRS 2016: Export to Excel issue

Tags: export-to-excel, ssrs-2016

When I try to export to Excel an SSRS Report, I have the following error:
[Export to Excel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWaRQ.png)

Attached is the version of SSRS installed:
[Version of SSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl8uQ.png)

I am using the Virtual Service Account as a Service Account. I read in other forums that when a Virtual Service Account and an Execution Account are used, SSRS has problems exporting to Excel. I have the same configuration in other virtual machines, but I do not have this issue.

I also have the issue exporting to Word. If someone have any idea about this issue, that would be helpfull to me.